# Powershell - Active Directory - Move users to an OU based on CSV file for employeeID and Date

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to make a script that will move Active Directory user accounts from 1 OU to another, based on dates and employeeID all from a CSV file.
The CSV file has the following columns:

"Employee Number" , "Start Date" , "Finish Date".
Example of one: Employee number: 123456, Start Date: 10/07/2020 End Date: 20/07/2020

The script would need to search Active Directory for the employee number, then if the "Start date" matches "todays date" then it moves them into OU X. If the "End Date" matches "Todays date" then it moves them into OU Y.

I wanted to do it by variables at the top like this:

```
$Importcsv = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Accounts.csv" | select "Employee Number", "Start Date", "End Date"
$xOU =  "OU=Start,OU=Test,DC=MyDomain,DC=local"
$yOU = "OU=End,OU=Test,DC=MyDomain,DC=local"
$CurrentDate = Get-Date -Format dd/MM/yyyy
```

Then I know I would need to use a "ForEach code, then nest all the varibles in, but getting it to match the dates to then move it to the OU? That's where I'm stuck!

Comment: Yes, it is possible if you can manage the user's Distinguished name. Here the employee number, is not the surname, not the given name or not any property of AD user object. We don't get any clue to get the distinguished name. We need at least the common name, current organisational unit and domain controller of the AD user to create the distinguished name. Otherwise, if possible try to provide the full distinguished name. That's very easy to do if we get that. Then you can do this `Move-ADObject -Identity "DistinguishedName" -Target "$NewOU"`.

Comment: the employeeID is populated in AD mate. It is possible to put another variable in to use the employeeid to get the DistinguishedName, then simply use that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best thing to do when comparing dates is to compare them as `[DateTime]` objects, not their string representations.

Also, your questions title says `EmployeeID`, but in the CSV you seem to use `EmployeeNumber`..
Those are two different user attributes in AD, so you need to make sure you are using the correct one.

For now, I'll assume you indeed want attribute `EmployeeID`:

```
$xOU = "OU=Start,OU=Test,DC=MyDomain,DC=local"
$yOU = "OU=End,OU=Test,DC=MyDomain,DC=local"
$CurrentDate = (Get-Date).Date

Import-Csv -Path "C:\Temp\Accounts.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $id = $_.'Employee Number'
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$id'" -Properties EmployeeID -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # convert the string dates from the CSV into real DateTime objects
        $startDate = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'Start Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null)
        $endDate   = [DateTime]::ParseExact($_.'Finish Date', 'dd/MM/yyyy', $null)
        switch ($CurrentDate) {
            $startDate {
                Write-Host "Moving user $($user.Name) to $xOU"
                $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $xOu
                break
            }
            $endDate {
                Write-Host "Moving user $($user.Name) to $yOU"
                $user | Move-ADObject -TargetPath $yOu
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "No user with EmployeeID '$id' found."
    }
}
```

Comment: A big THANK YOU!! that worked perfectly. I can see where I was going wrong as well, I was trying to force a variable in to the dates and it wasn't looking at the time correctly. The parseExact did it.